# How receive back JSON data from the server?

Tags: android, json, url, post

I  am sending data to a server using below code:

```
  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);

    try {

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}
```

Server is sending me JSON in response, how can I collect the data sent back to me.

Thanks

Thanks

Comment: if you are using json then following link may help you [Comsuming WCF Services With Android](http://fszlin.dymetis.com/post/2010/05/10/Comsuming-WCF-Services-With-Android.aspx)

Comment: Check this link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7428950/how-to-get-the-data-from-the-serverlocalhost-using-json

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be useful.

```
public class RestClient {

    public enum RequestMethod {
        GET,
        POST
    }

    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    private String url;

    private int responseCode;
    private String message;

    private String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public RestClient(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {
        switch(method) {
            case GET:
            {
                //add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for(NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }
                JSONObject jo = new JSONObject();


                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    for (int i = 0; i < params.size();i++)
                    {
                        jo.put(params.get(i).getName(),params.get(i).getValue());


                    }
                    StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jo.toString());
                    se.setContentType("text/xml"); 
                    se.setContentEncoding( new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")); 

                    request.setEntity(se);
                    //request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        //HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpClient client = HttpClientFactory.getThreadSafeClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

HttpClientFactory:

```
public class HttpClientFactory {

    private static DefaultHttpClient client;

    public synchronized static DefaultHttpClient getThreadSafeClient() {
        if (client != null)
            return client;
        client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        ClientConnectionManager mgr = client.getConnectionManager();
        HttpParams params = client.getParams();
        client = new DefaultHttpClient(new ThreadSafeClientConnManager(params,
                mgr.getSchemeRegistry()), params);
        return client;

    }
}
```

Now, to call it you simply use:

```
   RestClient c = new RestClient("http://somewebsite.com/register");
   c.AddHeader("Accept", "application/json");
   c.AddHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
   c.AddParam("UserName", user);
   c.AddParam("Password", password);
   c.Execute(RequestMethod.POST);

   JSONObject userKey = new JSONObject(c.getResponse());
```

Now you have a thread-safe, fairly easy to use set of classes you can use to call your services and extract your JSON data.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it in a different way, but its working :

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(URL);
    ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();
    String response = "";


    try {
// reponse string contains all the json data
         response = httpclient.execute(httppost,res);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
```